# Parameter in Url in Angular badly escaped

Tags: angularjs

I'm stuck with this issue I'm facing and couldn't solve it until now. I want to do a REST-Call to my backend with angular but the given parameter in the URL is badly escaped:

.../backend/artikel/getSingleResultById/**?0=1&1=0&2=0&3=3** <-- this is the part I'm talking about. I don't understand why it's so badly escaped. It should only be, in this case, 1003.

```
var REST_URL_ALLE_ARTIKEL = '.../backend/artikel/getAllByClass';
var REST_URL_EIN_ARTIKEL = '.../backend/artikel/getSingleResultById';

var artikelService = angular.module('artikelService', ['ngResource']);

artikelService.factory('ArtikelService', function ($resource) {

    return $resource(REST_URL_ALLE_ARTIKEL, {}, {
        getAlleArtikel: {method: 'GET', url: REST_URL_ALLE_ARTIKEL, isArray: true},
        getGesuchtenArtikel: {method: 'GET', url: REST_URL_EIN_ARTIKEL + '\\/:artnr', params: {artnr: '@artnr'}}
    });

});
```

This is my Service where the Method is defined. How can I pass the parameter in a proper way?

```
angular.module('frontend')
    .controller('ArtikelDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, ArtikelService) {
        $scope.testArtnr= $routeParams.artnr;

        $scope.gesuchterArtikel = ArtikelService.getGesuchtenArtikel($routeParams.artnr);


    });
```

and this is my controller where I call the method from the service.
when i print out testArtnr I get 1003, just as I need.

```
 .when('/artikel/:artnr', {
                templateUrl: 'views/artikelDetails.html',
                controller: 'ArtikelDetailCtrl'
            })
```

and this is the part in app.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArtikelService.getGesuchtenArtikel()` needs to be passed an object with an `artnr` property.

```
$scope.gesuchterArtikel = ArtikelService.getGesuchtenArtikel({
    artnr: $routeParams.artnr
});
```

It looks like currently it's treating "1003" as an object and each character as a property and appending each one to the call as the query string.

Comment: Thank you very much, this really saved my day!
can i ask you one more question: if i need a 2nd or a 3rd parameter, can i add them here, too? i.e.:
{
artnr: $routeParams.art,
someOther: whereverItComesFrom,
oneMore: whereverItComesFrom
}

Comment: Yep. By default they'll be appended to the URL as the query string. You can add them into the URL by adding them to the url as parameters (`:someOther`, etc)...